# Suggestion for ActionResult upload multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, actionresult

I have the following situation:

A document view where user can upload multiple files. A one(Document) to many(files) relationship. All these files are "inside" the document by its IDDocument property.

The user will make loads of .xml  files upload, each file upload fires that Action in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessSubmitUpload(HttpPostedFileBase attachments, Guid? idDocument)
    {
        //Validations
        var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(attachments.InputStream);
        if (xmlDocument.Root.Name.LocalName == "cteProc")
        {
             if (DocumentCommonHelper.SendXmlViaWebService(xmlDocument))
             {                  
                      _documentRepository.UpdateDocumentStatus(StatusOption.DocumentApproved);
             }
             else
             {
                      _documentRepository.UpdateDocumentStatus(StatusOption.DocumentPending);
             }
         }
   }
```

The logic is: If all files go correctly in the DocumentCommonHelper.SendXmlViaWebService(xmlDocument) , the document status must be Approved. But if one single file fails, the document status must be Pending.

The problem is that approach in this code is wrong. Because its changing the status of the document each time that the Action is executed, forgeting the others HttpPostedFileBase that are passed before.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to store the HttpPostedFileBase in the Session and retrieve them back when you need it

```
Session["HttpPostedFileBase"] = attachments;
```